# android - How to handle gson error

Tags: android

In my application if you click on the button then it calls the web service for the response and after mapping this response to some class using GSON at the time of mapping I'm getting the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@44c51f20 failed to deserialized json object
```

How to handle it. can anybody help me

### My Code

```
private OnClickListener exit3Listener = new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    if(!exit3status){   
        System.out.println("exit3 visible");
        //System.out.println("size"+RB_Constant.upcomingexits_obj.response.size());
        // Web service calling for exit restaurants.
        Exitexpand_pd = ProgressDialog.show(RB_UpcomingExits.this, "", "Please wait...", true);
        Thread t = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                try {               
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
                    ExitRestaurantsResponse = getExitsRestaurants();
                    System.out.println("exit3response"+ExitRestaurantsResponse);
                } catch (SoapFault e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
                rb_Exitexpand_Handler.post(rb_exitrestaurantres_HandlerResp);
                Exitexpand_pd.dismiss();
            }                                               
        };
        t.start();  

        listLayout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exit3status = true;

        if(!exit1status || exit2status || exit4status || exit5status)
        {
            //System.out.println("exit2 GONE");
            listLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listLayout4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listLayout5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            exit1status = false;
            exit2status = false;
            exit4status = false;
            exit5status = false;
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("exit3 GONE");
        listLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
        exit3status = false;                    
    }
    //LLExitDetails.invalidate();
}
};


final Runnable rb_exitrestaurantres_HandlerResp = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            check_exitrestrepWSResponse();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};


public void check_exitrestrepWSResponse() throws Exception{
    try{
        com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
        RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj = gson.fromJson(ExitRestaurantsResponse, Exitsrestaurants.class); // deserializes json into target2
        if( RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.status.equals("FAILED") != true &&
            RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.status.equals("SUCCESS") == true)
        {
            //System.out.println("total size:"+RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.totalrecords);
            System.out.println("res size:"+RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.size());
            if(ExitRestaurantsResponse.contains("Timeout expired") != true &&
                ExitRestaurantsResponse.contains("Cannot open database") != true &&
                ExitRestaurantsResponse.contains("error") != true )
            {
                // if Exits size is more zero or not
                if(RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.size() > 0){
                    if(RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.size() > 2){
                        if(RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.get(0).listRestaurants.size() > 0){                                                                                                                                
                            System.out.println("Exit3 Restaurants");
                            // Create the views on the fly instead of using the ListView
                            rbupcadapter3 = new UpcomingResultsListViewAdapter3(this);

                            int numItems3 = 0;
                            if(RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.get(0).listRestaurants.size() > 0)
                            {
                                numItems3 = RB_Constant.exitsrestaurants_obj.response.get(0).listRestaurants.size();
                                System.out.println("Exit3 restaurants size:"+numItems3);
                            }

                            //linearLayout2

                            for(int position=0; position < numItems3; position++)
                            {
                                View convertview = null;
                                convertview = rbupcadapter1.getView(position, convertview, null);
                                listLayout3.addView(convertview);                                                           
                            }                                                               

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No results in Exit3");
                            //toastMsg("No results in Exit3");
                        }   
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(JsonParseException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in check_exitrestrepWSResponse::"+e.toString());
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By using a try-catch-block?

```
try{
  // Try your GSON thing
} catch (JsonParseException e){
  // Do your Error handling
}
```

Comment: i am doing like this only but it's not working. Why this exception came?

Comment: You use the GSON-parser in two lines in your code and post 114 lines instead of those two? How lazy can one be... Also, I told you to post and example input (the JSON you're trying to parse). Also, the `Exitsrestaurants`-class is needed to see if your JSON is invalid.

Comment: The api i was using is unstable and sometimes was sending back an html string rather that json. catching the JsonParseException in this case helped me prevent my app crashing when malformed json arrives.